# Ask requestVisibleActions permission using Passport.js for moment insertion in Google+ API

Tags: node.js, google-plus, passport.js

I'm working on a Node.js application that uses Passport.js for authenticating with Google Plus. In a later stage now, we have introduced of adding activities using Google+'s [moment.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) to the user's Google+ feed when they leave reviews at our site. Posting using `moment.insert` needs a special permission called `requestvisibleactions`. The passport.js documentation doesn't say how I can ask for such permissions while logging in.

My current auth handler setup is like this:

```
app.get('/auth/google', redirect, passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write'],
    accessType: 'offline'
}));
```

Any pointers on how I can specify the `requestvisibleactions` permission mentioned in [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) during passport.js authentication is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that passport.js doesn't include support for `requestvisibleactions`, and the pull request to update it has been sitting there for a while. As we discussed on [Google+ insert moment with nodejs client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022561/google-insert-moment-with-nodejs-client/25037774) You will need to do two things:

1) Apply [this patch](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/pull/49/files), which lets passport.js be able to set the parameter correctly.

2) Set the action that you wish to be able to do as part of the call to `passport.authenticate`

I have not tested this (since I don't use passport.js), but once you have done (1), you should be able to use something like this to be able to post Add and Review moments:

```
app.get('/auth/google', redirect, passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write'],
    accessType: 'offline',
    requestVisibleActions: 'http://schema.org/AddAction http://schema.org/ReviewAction'
}));
```

Comment: i just have accesType and requestVisibleActions , but not work ? And try use google api explorer , request sent but nothing in my google plus activity,  why ??

where is i can find the post??

Comment: @masadizainul - It sounds like you should post this as a separate question, with illustrative code, so we can help figure out whats going on.